# Using LEFT JOIN in this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is an arbitrary example and this is the DB structure. I cannot change it.

I have two tables: [Phone] and [Models].

In both tables, the main columns are [Phone].[Name] and [Models].[Name].

Usually, both tables have related data; for example:

```
[Models.Name]         [Models.Quarter]
Samsung Galaxy S3      1
Samsung Galaxy S4      2
Samsung Galaxy S5      3


[Phone.Name]          [Phone.Quarter]
Samsung               1
```

Due to the table structure, the only way I can join both tables is through column Name and Quarter. So I end up using a LEFT JOIN like so and I get the result I need:

```
SELECT Models.*, Phone.* 
from dbo.Models left join Phone
on left(Models.Name, LEN(Phone.Name)) = Phone.Name 
WHERE 
[Phone.Quarter] = [Models.Quarter]
```

Unfortunately, there are some cases where [Models] has data, but [Phone]; in this case, [Models] has the 3 records, but [Phone] does not. Here, the `WHERE` clause defeats the whole purpose of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Does it make sense to use two `LEFT JOIN` with the same tables?

Comment: Why can't you just add the `[Phone.Quarter] = [Models.Quarter]` to your on clause?  Or is that what you're asking?  You can certainly have multiple columns in an on clause.

Comment: If LEN(Phone.Name) > LEN(Models.Name) I think that fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when using outer joins, if you want to keep the join null values from the outer table, you must put limits on the inner table as part of the join syntax.

```
SELECT Models.*, Phone.* 
FROM dbo.Models 
LEFT JOIN Phone
  on left(Models.Name, LEN(Phone.Name)) = Phone.Name 
 and [Phone.Quarter] = [Models.Quarter]
```

OR this, though it's not as elegant and suffers from the fact you can't distinguish a NULL from a join vs a NULL value.

```
SELECT Models.*, Phone.* 
FROM dbo.Models 
LEFT JOIN Phone
  on left(Models.Name, LEN(Phone.Name)) = Phone.Name 
WHERE ([Phone.Quarter] = [Models.Quarter] OR [Phone.Quarter] is null)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't think of adding that condition to the ON clause. Thanks for the post.